# Python if being ignored

Tags: python, if-statement

It is skipping the `if Ctype == 1` (`2`, `3`, etc.) down at the bottom, no idea why.

```
print("Starting game.")
print("Game Started.")
print('\n')
CharName = input('Create a character name: ')
print('\n' * 20)
print('Class Selection: (Ensure it as written as you read it)')
print('\n')
print('Classes:')
print('[1] Heavy')
print('[2] LightFooted')
print('[3] Warrior')
print('\n')
print('To Come:')
print('Stealth')
print('\n')
Ctype = input('Choose class: ')
if Ctype == 1:
    print('test')
if Ctype == 2:
    print('test')
if Ctype == 3:
    print('test')
if Ctype == 4:
    print('Try again... another time.')
    time.wait(2)
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, you compare to integer, convert one of those

Comment: the input is a string and `"1" != 1`

Comment: (at least in Python3)

Comment: your code would work in `python 2.7+` but wont in `python 3+` without some tweaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string in Python3.

So `Ctype` is a string. You then compare with an integer, thus the equality check fails.

Convert the string to an int, like this:

```
Ctype = int(Ctype)
```

Comment: Will try it now. Yep, makes sense and works, will keep it in mind for future. Appreciated.

Comment: Good @TGBFProject, accept the answer then! =)